# Make element fit page scroll width with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a header with `width: 100%` and I want to make it automatically adjustable not only to screen width, but to page full width that can be stretched beyond screen width by other elements. I can do it with JS, but I wonder if it is possible to use pure CSS to achieve this.

In the example below the A block is intended to be the same size as the B block, but it is much shorter on small screens (just scroll everything to the right and you can see).

```css
html,body{
  position:relative; width:100%;
}
#A{
  position:relative; width:100%;
  background:lightblue; color:white;
}
#B{
  position:relative; width:5000px;
  background:darkblue; color:white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="A">A</div>
<div id="B">B</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Giving `width: 100%` to A will work for this

Comment: @Abinthaha, it doesn't work (at least in Firefox and Opera).

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding `display: grid` to the container, in this case `body`

```css
body {
  display: grid;
}

#A {
  background: lightblue;
  color: white;
}

#B {
  position: relative;
  width: 5000px;
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="A">A</div>
  <div id="B">B</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It really works in modern browsers, but is there a solution that can be used in older ones?

Comment: There may be, unfortunately I don't have more time tonight to check :) Hopefully you'll get further answers

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap the two divs (A & B) inside another you can achieve this.

```css
html,body{
position:relative; width:100%;
}
#A{
position:relative; width:100%;
background:lightblue; color:white;
}
#B{
position:relative; width:5000px;
background:darkblue; color:white;
}
.header-wrap { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
<div class="header-wrap">
<div id="A">A</div>
<div id="B">B</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is, if the B block is shorter than screen width, the A block is not 100%.

Comment: But it seems to work if you add `min-width:100%;` to `.header-wrap`

Comment: please add this, and I will mark your post as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```css
 html,
  body {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
  }
  
  #B {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   top: 100%;
   left: 0;
   background: lightblue;
   color: white;
  }
  
  #A {
   position: relative;
   width: 5000px;
   background: darkblue;
   color: white;
            min-width:100%;
  }
```

```html
 <div id="A"><div id="B">B</div>A</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but as in the other answer, the problem is, if the B block is shorter than screen width (its width does not necessarily equal to 5000px), the A block is not 100%.

Comment: if tou want make a min-width 100% of the screen just do it: `#A{min-width:100%}`

Comment: i add it to the answer. and if you want that only the #B will min-height 100% you also can do it `#B{min-width:100vw}`

Comment: In my case the content in the B block can be any width, but if it has `position: absolute;`, it will not stretch if something in it is wider than screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your A div a max-width of 5000px as well as width:100%

```
#A{
 position:relative; 
 width:100%;
 max-width:5000px;
 background:lightblue; 
 color:white;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the B block in my example is wider than screen width.